# Iterate dictionary when the value is unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Part of the dictionary looks like this:

```
response = {
    u'numberOfComments': 22, 
    u'publicationPeriod': {
        u'value': u'Fall 2012',
        u'label': u'Publication Period'}, 
    u'timeTables': [
        {
             u'action': u'NPRM',
             u'actionQualifier': u'NPRM',
             u'date': u'01/10/2012',
             u'frCitation':
             u'77 FR 1434'
        }, {
            u'action': u'Final Rule',
            u'actionQualifier': u'Final Rule', 
            u'date': u'08/13/2012',
            u'frCitation': u'77 FR 48072'
        }
    ]
}
```

The contents of `response` contains a mix of primitives, nested dictionaries, and lists of dictionaries.

How do I get the value in a mix of types within a dictionary?

Ultimately, I want just the `numberofComments` which in here is 22.

I've tried:

```
for dic in response:
    if response.has_key('numberOfComments'):
        while type(dic)==int:

            if dic['numberOfComments']<Max:
                content={
                     'docketID':docketID,
                     'title': dic['title'],
                     'numberOfComments': item['numberOfComments']        
                    }

            print content
```

but 'dic' is not 'int', so `if dic['numberOfComments']<Max`:' gives me

```
'TypeError: string indices must be integers'
```

If I try `dic=int(dic)`,

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'publicationPeriod'
```

I have also tried doing:

```
​for dic, value in response:
    if type(dic.values()) != dict:
        if response.has_key('numberOfComments'):
            for value in dic.values():
                print 'ok'
```

But obviously can't do that because it's not just dictionary and it gives the error:

```
'unicode' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Comment: maybe the collections module can be of help (for conditional counting), if you want to check types, try the isinstance(1, (int,)) which tends to be the most reliable for type checking, maybe try a bit of printing so that you see what you are trying to compare

Comment: Why are you iterating? Isn't this just `response['numberOfComments']`?

Comment: @ahed87 Yeah, I've been printing every step of the way. Thus far works fine-  `for dic, value in response.items():
    if response.has_key('numberOfComments'):`  But the problem is `if dic['numberOfComments']<Max:`

Comment: @user2357112 Good point. I'll try that once I get out of this :)  `print dic.values()['numberOfComments']` gives me `'unicode' object has no attribute 'values'`. It seems to be bc the values are not consistently _int_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get exclusively the `u'numberOfComments` key you may use `response[u'numberOfComments']`.

Your code seams a bit confusing regarding dictionary iteration.

When you iterate over a dict (`for x in dict`) `x` is assigned to each one of the keys in the dict.

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'x': [], 3: None}
>>> for x in d:
...     print(x)
... 
a
x
3
```

Now if you want to iterate simultaneously on keys and values in a `for key, value in dic` fashion you may do so using the `items()` method. Such as:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'x': [], 3: None}
>>> for key, value in d.items():
...     print('{}: {}'.format(key, value))
... 
a: 1
x: []
3: None
```

Hope I could help. :)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm having trouble iterating bc **value** is sometimes 'string'/'integer'/'dictionary'.  
I wanted to compare the value to 'Max' and save the value.  

`for dic, value in response.items():  <br/>
   if response.has_key('numberOfComments'):  <br/>
       if dic['numberOfComments']<Max:  <br/>
            print 'ok'`  <br/>
                                                                
but then get the error `'string indices must be integers'`

Comment: Oh, that was quick haha. 'numberOfComments' is all I need. I need to save the number if it's smaller than 'Max'.

Comment: Does this works: `for key, value in response.items(): <br/> if k == u'numberOfItems' and type(v) == int and v < Max: <br/> print 'ok'`?

Comment: `for key, value in response.items(): 
    if key == u'numberOfItems':` returns an empty set

Comment: `for key, value in response.items(): 
    if type(value)==int:
        print value`  Now this, this gives _22_!!!! yeah!!!!

Comment: I was about to send [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nathan-cruz77/2010e6e4ad2152e86701a50d8c3ffd55). It was a simple typo on the key there, hehe. im glad you could figure it out. xD